# Error 404: when rendering jquery-1.4.1.min.js from Script folder

Tags: asp.net, iis

- Website: https://abc.xyz.com/emrsso
- IIS Setup: Site > SHC > EMRSSO
- Virtual Path: /EMRSSO
- Default Document: SSOLogin.aspx
- Physical path: D:\Renesan\SHCTest\EMRSSO

And also there is Scripts folder under EMRSSO e.g. D:\Renesan\SHCTest\EMRSSO\Scripts.

Then there is jquery-3.4.1.min.js under Scripts folder e.g. D:\Renesan\SHCTest\EMRSSO\Scripts\jquery-3.4.1.min.js

when I visit https://abc.xyz.com/emrsso, It is 404 error or jquery-3.4.1.min.js, on debugging I found in chrome dev tool path is showing as
'https://abc.xyz.com/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' instead of 'https://abc.xyz.com/emrsso/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'

when I visit https://abc.xyz.com/emrsso/SSOLogin.aspx, jquery-3.4.1.min.js is rendering successfully and on debugging in chrome dev tool path is showing as
'https://abc.xyz.com/emrsso/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'  which is fine.

When I debug my application through Visual Studio jquery-3.4.1.min.js is rendering successfully and working fine.

ASPX Code for jquery-3.4.1.min.js:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="SSOLogin.aspx.vb" Inherits="EHR_Web.SSOLogin" %>

<script src="https://global.oktacdn.com/okta-signin-widget/5.2.0/js/okta-sign-in.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://global.oktacdn.com/okta-signin-widget/5.2.0/css/okta-sign-in.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have gone through other question:
[Why IIS doesn't handle relative path the same way IIS Express does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37556913/why-iis-doesnt-handle-relative-path-the-same-way-iis-express-does)

However I did not find any resolution. what can be wrong here?

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this answer for explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361168/20058276.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resolving your URL, this keeps the path consistent regardless of which folder a page/control is in.

```
<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl?view=netframework-4.8.1