# Bad Request - Invalid Hostname ASP.net Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#

After debugging my web api in Visual Studio 2019, I can visit it via localhost:11112. I would like to visit my website on a different computer from which it is being served upon that is also on the same network. To do this I should be able to visit that computers address which is 192.168.1.129:11112.

However when visiting this address I get a 'Bad request, invalid host name' error. Even if I visit it on the same machine as the website is being served on.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I already reference this answer but it not work too

[Bad Request - Invalid Hostname ASP.net Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35247847/bad-request-invalid-hostname-asp-net-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: did you try localhost:11112? if you did, you have add some specification for the url in configuration file

Comment: @FatihTAN localhost:11112 is working like the picture above, and I try  config in applycationhost.config  , but it is still not working :      <binding protocol="http"  bindingInformation="*:11112:127.0.0.1" />

Comment: I recommend that: <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress> and <IISExpressSSLPort /> in PropertyGroup node. Also in <ProjectExtensions> -->    <VisualStudio> --> <FlavorProperties> --> <WebProjectProperties> add/modify <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>, <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>, <IISUrl>http://127.0.0.1:11112/</IISUrl>, <DevelopmentServerPort>0</DevelopmentServerPort>

Comment: @FatihTAN please guide me more detail, what is file that I need add config ?

Comment: of course i will prepare an answer

Comment: @PhuongPhamVan can you please check your appsettings.json? if that has not "AllowedHosts": "*" your appsettings.json should look like this https://pastebin.com/ADxnXpfE