# Wordpress site returning 'Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)'

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I've been working on a small Wordpress website recently. It's running on a server with HELM version 3.2, and the database is MYSQL 5. It was working fine for the last week or so, over which time I was making minor edits to the content.

Recently, the website has become completely inaccessible for some reason, only returning a blank page with the text: 'Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)'. I've looked at the database and the wp-config file, but everything looks to be correct and nothing has changed there.

Is there any way I can get the website working again, and is there a reason this has happened?

Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044470/bad-request-invalid-hostname-while-connect-to-localhost-via-wifi-from-mobile-ph

Answer (score 0):

That is server issue. You can find details about the error in error.log file. You can find the file in logs directory or in root hosting directory (if shared hosting ).