# Deploying a webapp written in asp.net locally(in a LAN) using IIS EXPRESS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express, lan

I have an application written in asp.net (web forms , not MVC). Entire thing works fine within the system.

Once I tried to run it within the closed network, other PC are unable to access the site.

Peer machines are displaying a **Bad Request- Invalid Hostname** error.

How to allow access to all PC in LAN to access the app?

Comment: This could be caused by so many different things. Have you checked your firewall settings are allowing access to the port number you have the site running under? What URL have you given people to access the site?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/express-specific.html#enable-external-access You can find what Microsoft recommends, and what Jexus Manager can simplify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bad Request- Invalid Hostname while connect to localhost via wifi from mobile phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044470/bad-request-invalid-hostname-while-connect-to-localhost-via-wifi-from-mobile-ph)

Comment: You really shouldn't use IISExpress if you intend other machines to access it. Are you trying to do a production deployment or shared testing environment? Then set up a web server with full IIS running on it. IISExpress is really only for local development.